# table design for tracking head-to-head match records?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I am having trouble coming up with a workable table design for tracking head-to-head match results between users.

All users have a UID. Individual match results are stored in another table, and each match has its own UID.

What I want is to be able to pull something like this with a simple select:

```
Player   vs.    Opponent   Wins   Losses   Draws
Bob             John       5      2        1
Bob             Sam        0      3        2
John            Bob        2      5        1
```

I can pull this data out of the raw match results with some manipulation in PHP, but it's rather costly so I'd like to use cron jobs and store these "finished" statistics in a table for quick reads.

What's tripping me up is the fact that one data set (2 players, win, loss, draw counts) can be read in two directions, depending on which player's point of view you want, as depicted above for Bob and John.

I could make a table like this:

```
[player]  [opponent]  [wins]  [losses]  [draws]
```

but then each "set" would require two rows...

```
[player]  [opponent]  [wins]  [losses]  [draws]
bob       john        5       2         1
john      bob         2       5         1
```

and that duplication seems like it might cause me problems later, though off the top of my head I can't think of a reason why, just DRY and all that...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the duplication approach you mention used effectively. So long as you're aware of the duplication, it's not too difficult to handle.

If you want to avoid the duplication, you'll probably need more code, and more code complexity: to show all the results for a single player, you'd need to find the records where that player is *either* "Player" or "Opponent".

One (I'd argue) useful way to report all the players' records (versus their opponents) would be to display each "versus" records twice -- once as a Player, grouped together, and once as an Opponent, in each of the sets of records for their opponents:

```
Player   vs.    Opponent   Wins   Losses   Draws
Bob             John       5      2        1
Bob             Sam        0      3        2
John            Bob        2      5        1
John            Sam        1      2        1
Sam             Bob        3      0        2
Sam             John       2      1        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table (MatchID, Player1ID, Player2ID, Player1Score, Player2Score ...), with **one** row for each match (i.e. no duplication)

You can get all matches for a player via:

```
SELECT * from Matches WHERE Player1ID = @ID OR Player2ID = @ID
```

Possibly slightly more useful, though, is to rearrange the data slightly so it's always player and opponent:

```
SELECT MatchID, Player1ID, Player2ID, Player1Score, Player2Score ... FROM Matches where Player1ID = @ID
UNION
SELECT MatchID, Player2ID, Player1ID, Player2Score, Player1Score ... FROM Matches where Player2ID = @ID
```

(note that both the ID and the score order is reversed in the second union statement)

You can also generalise this for stats building:

```
 SELECT stats.Player, stats.Opponent, SUM(stats.PlayerWin) AS Wins, SUM(stats.Draw) AS Draws, SUM(stats.OpponentWin) AS Losses
 FROM (
    SELECT Player1ID AS Player, Player2ID AS Opponent, 
        CASE WHEN Player1Score > Player2Score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PlayerWin,
        CASE WHEN Player1Score = Player2Score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Draw, 
        CASE WHEN Player2Score > Player1Score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OpponentWin
    UNION
    SELECT Player2ID AS Player, Player1ID AS Opponent, 
        CASE WHEN Player2Score > Player1Score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PlayerWin,
        CASE WHEN Player2Score = Player1Score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Draw, 
        CASE WHEN Player1Score > Player2Score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OpponentWin
     ) stats
 GROUP BY stats.Player, stats.Opponent
```

I guess my general point is you can have it either way, they're roughly equally complicated (if you put data into the database twice, you have to make sure you keep it in sync when you update it. If you put data into the database once, you have to count it twice when you're doing stats. Also, if you put data into the database twice, that complicates things a bit from the database side since MatchID won't be unique any more.)

Comment: Hi Simon! You have solved a slightly more complex problem than the one I currently face. My matches have no scoring, just winner, loser, or draw. I appreciate the insight, though. It will be useful in the future.

Comment: If you just have W/L/D attached to a match (how do you tell which player is the winner?), then replace the `Player1Score > Player2Score` with whatever logic you have for determining who the winner is.

Comment: the record entry stores all the data regarding the actual play: who, when, and winner. The loser is inferred by stats scripts as being *not the winner* :-)